# Bash complains "have not a command" when login

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file named "upstart" in /etc/bash_completion.d/ with the following content:

```
# bash-completion for the upstart event-based init replacement
# (http://upstart.ubuntu.com / https://launchpad.net/upstart)
#
# We don't provide completion for 'init' itself for obvious reasons.
have initctl &&
_upstart_jobs()
{
  initctl list|awk '{print $1}'|sort -u
} &&
```

The confusing part is the line `have initctl &&`, I have configured bash to source 
all files in /etc/bash_completion.d/ and every time I login it complains 
that `command have cannot be found`. What is that line for?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: maybe you should install `bash-completion` package.

In general, you don't need to manually source the files in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.
It is automatically imported by `bash_completion` script.
`bash_completion` script is called by `/etc/bash.bashrc` (at least for Ubuntu and Arch Linux), which would be called by default.

In Ubuntu, `bash_completion` script is in `bash-completion` package and placed in `/etc/bash_completion`
In Arch Linux, `bash_completion` script is in `bash-completion` package and placed in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`

Therefore, installing `bash-completion` script would help if you are using Ubuntu or Arch Linux.